# Why is this xml parsing producing only one element?

Tags: php, xml

I am having trouble parsing this xml. I want to access the array of item(s). I have tried $xml->channel->item and $xml->channel["item"] but neither works.

Here is the php code I have:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("my file.xml");
$channel = $xml->channel;
$items = $channel->item;
var_dump($channel);
var_dump($items); //This is only showing one item, when there are many
```

Here is the beginning of the output for `var_dump($channel)`

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (7) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "Title"
  ["link"]=>
  string(30) "mylink/"
  ["description"]=>
  string(128) "description"
  ["pubDate"]=>
  string(31) "Fri, 27 Jun 2014 04:24:24 -0700"
  ["generator"]=>
  string(57) "http://Tumblr2WordPress/0.4(tumblr2wordpress.benapps.net)"
  ["language"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["item"]=>
  array(374) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#69 (7) {
      ["link"]=>
      string(46) "link"
      ["pubDate"]=>
      string(31) "Thu, 26 Jun 2014 15:19:41 +0000"
      ["category"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#443 (0) {
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#444 (1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["domain"]=>
            string(8) "category"
            ["nicename"]=>
            string(7) "regular"
          }
        }
      }
      ["guid"]=>
      string(46) "link"
      ["comment"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#445 (0) {
      }
      ["title"]=>
      string(18) "Ran 8 miles today!"
      ["description"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#446 (0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=> more here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If items is a grouping of items, keep in mind you're still dealing with a SimpleXML object. Use a foreach loop to easily go over each item and extract its properties.

```
foreach($channel->item as $singleItem) {
    //item properties are accessible for each
}
```

Another option you have is to use simpleXML's xpath function to return an array of objects that match your xpath. I can share an example of that if you want as well.